# Resque with multiple workers: What order?

Tags: ruby, scheduled-tasks, resque

I'm trying to understand the sequencing logic of Resque. I believe each queue is processed on a FIFO basis (standard queue behaviour), but say I have several queues - all with pending jobs - and two workers processing "*" (ie all queues).

What algorithm decides which job will be processed next? If it was a universal FIFO, it would be the oldest job on *any* queue, but it looks to me like there's some sort of queue rotation going on instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/multi_queue.rb

If it's working in blocking mode (which it does by default), then it uses Redis' [BLPOP](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) method, which accepts a list of queues, and will pop and return a value from the first queue to have data.

Redis' BLPOP enqueues clients on a first-come, first-served basis. When given multiple queue keys, it simply iterates through them and sets up blocking per key. See https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_list.c#L781-815

Resque is going to build a list of queues to test by just getting something like `SMEMBERS queues`, which means that queues will be prioritized in the order that the SMEMBERS command returns them in. That's a set operation, which means that its order is undefined; you're mostly at Redis' mercy.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps for that you should know a bit of redis because resque internally user `[blpop][1]` check [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/multi_queue.rb#L58)

Now how `blpop` work let say you have 2 list or queue `king` and `queen`

Consider the Following Scenario

```
1) when one or more message exist in `king` and `queen` has no message i.e empty

  blop would pop a single message from `king` 

2) when `queen` has one or more message but `king` doesnt 

  blop would pop a message from `queen`

3) when but `king` or `queen` both has message in them. 

now the order of queues decide from which the message would be popped 

Let say `king` has 3 message and `queen` has 2 message 

and let say the order is 

redis.blpop "king","queen",0

blop would pop message from `king` 3 times(until it has no longer message in them) and then would pop the message from queue name "queen"
```

You can refer redis [documentation](http://redis.io/commands#list) on list and  blop for more information

Hope this make sense

Comment: Why do people say resque internally uses `blpop`? Their readme specifically says the default is to poll every 5 seconds, and redis `monitor` log reveals `lpop` being used. Is this a recent behavior, and is it possible to switch to the `blpop` mode?